# Quickblox WebRTC freezes after background

Tags: ios, webrtc, quickblox

I use quickblox webrtc framework. And can't resolve bug: I call User 2 from user 1, after call started I am going to background on user 1, red line on top showing. Wait 10 sec, after that go come back to app and see freezes on QBRTCRemoteVideoView 3 sec video stopped, 3 sec continuing stream and repeated until call finished.

Comment: Please create an issue on [github](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk) and attach stats report.

Comment: `[QBRTCConfig setStatsReportTimeInterval:1.f];` - method for enabling stats report.

Comment: and what I must do with this method?